# How do I find unique rows in a numpy array with different shaped rows?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

My numpy array consists of lists of different orders as rows. Eg:

```
array = [[item1, item2],
         [item1, item2],
         [item1, item2, item3],
         [item1, item2, item3, item4]]

#required output
unique_rows = [[item1, item2],
               [item1, item2, item3],
               [item1, item2, item3, item4]]
```

I want to find unique rows for an array like this where a row length maybe 8 or 80 in length. I tried to use the np.unique() method but I got this error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Comment: This isn't a numpy array; it's a list of lists.  Even if wrapped in `np.array(...)` is a object dtype array, which is practically the same thing.  `np.unique` sorts the array and looks for adjacent pairs.  Equality between those lists is problematic.

Comment: I see. I am still new to python so I have been following solutions on StackOverflow for doing things. This particular doubt had no direct solutions whatsoever so I was at a loss on proceeding further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the items are hashable, you could try:

```
set(tuple(i) for i in array)
```

which gives:

```
{('item1', 'item2'),
 ('item1', 'item2', 'item3'),
 ('item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4')}
```